# Confusion regarding precedence of C operators

Tags: c, operators

I"m quite confused about the following block of code:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

printf("%d ", c - 3 && b++ > c);

printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
```

Initially, I thought that the output would be `0 1 3 3` since b would become 3 due to the side effect of the post-fix operator. But, the output I am getting is `0 1 2 3`. Why is this?

Specifically, to evaluate `c - 3 && b++ > c` I used the C operator precedence table (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence#cite_note-1) to determine the operator precedence. Postfix increment operator has much higher precendence than the logical AND operator. So why is the output the way it is? Do logical operators somehow bypass operator precedence in C?

Comment: `c - 3` is 0 (false) so the left part of the condition is false. Since false AND anything is false, the right hand part doesn't need to be evaluated... so it isn't evaluated...

Comment: you should make that an answer

Comment: Logical AND will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks for the encouragement, but I'm sure there are '00s of SO questions on this theme already... :-)

Comment: Possibly, but questions like these might help someone in the future

Comment: PS: Now that you've seen this and appreciate the consequences, make a vow that you will never again write code like this.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yup. I'll try to be more thorough when looking for a question that may answer mine next time :)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Please never use a closed-as-duplicate as duplicate target. Try to use a canonical post. In this case you can find a list of such below the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) -> FAQ -> operators.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the advice and the link... I'm waiting to see you also inform the person who answered this FAQ that it is better to vote to close obvious FAQ's than to answer them again and again and again...

Comment: @Fe2O3 They should know as much indeed. Sadly the SO site design encourages such "rep farming" over duplicate moderation. I think it is a lost cause.

Comment: I'm not sure why my question was downvoted. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence dictates how operands are grouped, not the order in which they are evaluated.  So this:

```
c - 3 && b++ > c
```

Parses as this:

```
(c - 3) && ((b++) > c)
```

The logical operators `&&` and `||` have what's referred to as *short circuit* behavior, which means if the result can be determined from just the left operand then the right operand is not evaluated.

The left operand of `&&` is `c - 3`.  This evaluates to 0, which means the entire `&&` expression evaluates to 0 and the right operand, i.e. `b++ > c` is not evaluated, so `b` is not incremented.